# Modify Datepicker translations on runtime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm tweaking an existing jQuery UI 1.10.4 Datepicker to support several languages. I want to use the official translations without modifications so I'm able to upgrade in the future. However, I also need to change some terms or add missing ones.

I'm trying out this:

```
$.datepicker.regional["es"]["buttonText"] = "Foo!";
$('.is-a-date').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        buttonImage: '/img/datepicker.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

I've verified that `$.datepicker.regional["es"]` contains the new values and `buttonText` is localisable (it works fine if I add it right at `jquery.ui.datepicker-es.js`). Everything is enclosed in a `jQuery(function(){...})` wrapper. But my custom texts do not show up anywhere.

What am I missing? Do I need to reinitialise something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the changes you do to the regional you should register them useing the `setDefaults` function:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"])
```

Check the next example - the text on the next-month button is changed to "Bar!".

```js
$.datepicker.regional["es"]["buttonText"] = "Foo!";
$.datepicker.regional["es"]["nextText"] = "Bar!";

$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["es"])

$('.is-a-date').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        buttonImage: '/img/datepicker.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/i18n/datepicker-es.js"></script>

<input class="is-a-date" />
```

Comment: That was it, thank you very much. In my real code I've decided to loop non-empty keys in `$.datepicker.regional` and refresh all loaded languages—I hope it isn't a stupid idea.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to use one in my answer:)

Comment: I don't trust whoever will code stuff later (it might even be me!) :)